# Magento 2 - Add additional text before attribute

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, layout, attributes

I use this code to display `brand` attribute value in the product view page:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.brand" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getBrand</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">brand</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">brand</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="brand"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

How I can display Brand text before this attribute value, to be in the product page something like:

**Brand:** Apple

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>`

change 'none' to 'default'